# Override appveyor publish profile

Tags: msbuild, continuous-deployment, appveyor

I have an MVC 5 application we're moving from on-premise to the Azure cloud. Currently, we have several publish profiles, one per environment, which we determine using a powershell script. One of our goals is to make the building scripts and infrastructure as simple as possible, so I was wondering if I could make it so that using only my `appveyor.yml` file I could set the publish profile to be used, so

Is there a way to set the publish profile from the `appveyor.yml` file?
If not what are my choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your PowerShell script as part of desired build step in [pipeline](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#build-pipeline). It is possible can run commands [right from YAML file or UI](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#script-blocks-in-build-configuration) or check-in your PowerShell script into repository and run `.ps1` file. You might consider using [secure variables](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#secure-variables) to avoid checking in things like connection strings into repo in clear text.

However this custom script/profiles approach will not allow you to use [built-in WAP artifacts packaging](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-phase/#packaging-web-application-projects-wap) and you will be also needed to use custom script instead of automatic [MSBuild mode](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-phase/). Which is OK, but a little bit more scripting. Also you will be needed to [publish artifacts](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/) so it will be available for deployment.

Maybe easier option is to let AppVeyor do all [build and WAP artifacts packaging/publishing automatically](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/web-deploy/#creating-web-deploy-package), and then use [built-in Web Deployment](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/web-deploy/#web-deploy-deployment-settings) with [Web Deploy parametrization](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/web-deploy/#web-deploy-parametrization) instead of multiple publishing profiles.

But if you decide to go with custom scripts, and multiple publishing profiles, you still can use use [built-in Web Deployment](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/web-deploy/#web-deploy-deployment-settings) with artifacts created by your scripts.